# double with no digits default format

Tags: mysql, laravel, double, sqldatatypes

As laravel migration I put a field as `double()` without assign the number of digits of decimals and totals. In the mysql db are stored as `double` without, again, numbers of digits.

So I try to search in laravel and mysql docs but with no hope, the question is What is the default rappresentation of a double field without the numbers of digits?
Ok the are used 8 bytes, but how?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `FLOAT(m,n)` or `DOUBLE(m,n)`; use only `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`.  The `(m,n)` causes double-rounding and/or truncation.  The intent of `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` is represent "scientific" (not "money") values that have a wide range of precision and range.

`FLOAT` holds about 7 *significant* digits; `DOUBLE`, 16.  The decimal point can be virtually anywhere.

If you want "fixed point" numbers, use `DECIMAL(m,n)`.  For example `DECIMAL(8,2)` can represent up to a million dollars or Euros, down to the cent.